# Alert display on building code of android in phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am getting a alert in starting in emulator using phone gap technology in android.

"Exception building coredova js globals: ReferenceError: can't find variable: org for key"exec".

actually i don't understand why this come.same code works on blackberry.

please help

Answer (score 1):

the cordova.js for blackberry and android is different. Replace your coredova.js file with the corresponding js for android.

Answer (score -1):

thanks @AnhSirk...

I hv also done that stupid mistake...copy the same "cordova.js" file for blackberry into android project.... and receiving the same Alert message -

Exception building cordova JS globals: Reference: org is not defined for key “exec”

By Replacing with "cordova.js" file for Android, Problem get solved.

Thanks, 
Rajani Dhawan